# How to stub a method in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, stub

I want to stub out the space_available_mb method in SubmissionsController so that it returns 5. This doesn't work. It returns the correct space on the real hard disk.

if `space_available_mb` is commented out, an expectation error is thrown, which means `should_receive` works correctly. However, it doesn't return 5, but the real number, which means `and_return` fails for some reason.

Further debugging reveals that `and_return` is actually called, but only after the method has run and returned the real number.

```
Scenario: Hard Disk Space is low on new submission
  Given I am on the new_submission page
  And hard disk space is low
  Then I should see "Low disk space!"

Given /^hard disk space is low$/ do
  SubmissionsController.should_receive(:space_available_mb).and_return(5)
end

class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  include FileManager

  def new
    space = space_available_mb
    ...
  end
end

module FileManager
  def space_available_mb
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/examples/rspec_doubles/features) help you?

Comment: @farnoy that explains how to create a mock object. in this case, I need to stub a controller method.

Comment: Note that this is usually not a good idea. Cucumber should usually test the full stack. Your use case—where you're essentially trying to stub an external service—is about the only time that this is advisable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on a mock framework, the syntax differs, but what you're trying to accomplish is stubbing a method on **any instance** of your controller. In RSpec, you have [this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-8/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class). So according to your attempts:

```
Given /^hard disk space is low$/ do
  SubmissionsController.any_instance.should_receive(:space_available_mb).and_return(5)
end
```

If you plan to use any other mock frameworks, there's bound to be a method like this `any_instance` of RSpec's.

Comment: unfortunately, any_instance doesn't seem to make a difference. Interestingly, It is reported that the method is called, because if I comment out the call, a MockExpectationError is thrown. However, the return value is not substituted. (doesn't return 5)

Comment: it turns out that `any_instance` indeed was one of the issues. The other issue was that the `hard disk is low` step should come before the `I'm on the new_submission page`

Comment: Can you `puts SubmissionsController.new.space_available_mb` for both the solution above and `SubmissionsController.any_instance.stub(:space_available_mb).and_return(5)` ?

Comment: I'm using break points. `should_receive` and `stub` both work fine, only the former also requires the `space_available_mb` to be called

Comment: so everything that you asked about was covered here?

Comment: as I said, the issue was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390220/how-to-stub-a-method-in-cucumber/9414647#comment11904758_9414647 . The solution for the problem is that I should have used `any_instance` and that I should have put the `hard disk is low` step before the `I am on the new submission page`, because originally, the `new` method in the `SubmissionsController` was executed before the stubbing took place.

Comment: I'm getting  undefined method `any_instance_recorder_for' for nil:NilClass and this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18753331/1123985 isn't helping. I'm trying to stub an active record object in each scenario. Tried in rspec 2.14 and rspec 2.99.

Comment: @davidtingsu you need to require rspec doubles. Put the following in your env.rb file for cucumber: `require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'`