# Rspec any_instance.stub raises undefined method `any_instance_recorder_for' for nil:NilClass exception

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here is the class that I'm testing contained in **Foo.rb**:

```
class Foo
    def bar
        return 2
    end
end
```

Here is the my test contained in **Foo_spec.rb**:

```
require "./Foo.rb"

describe "Foo" do
    before(:all) do
        puts "#{Foo == nil}"
        Foo.any_instance.stub(:bar).and_return(1)
    end

    it "should pass this" do
        f = Foo.new
        f.bar.should eq 1
    end
end
```

I am getting the following output:

```
false
F

Failures:

  1) Foo Should pass this
     Failure/Error: Foo.any_instance.stub(:bar).and_return(1)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `any_instance_recorder_for' for nil:NilClass
     # ./Foo_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./Foo_spec.rb:9 # Foo Should pass this
```

I've consulted [the doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class) and the example given is passing on my machine (so it isn't a problem with the rspec code), but it isn't giving me any information on what I might be doing wrong. The error message is also quite confusing as it's telling me not to call `.any_instance` on a `nil:NilClass`, but as I proved with my output, `Foo` isn't `nil`. How am I supposed to call `.any_instance.stub` on my custom object?

I'm using Ruby `1.9.3` and rspec `2.14.5`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `before(:each)` for stubbing.

> Stubs in `before(:all)` are not supported. The reason is that all stubs and mocks get cleared out after each example, so any stub that is set in `before(:all)` would work in the first example that happens to run in that group, but not for any others.

[rspec-mocks readme](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#use-beforeeach-not-beforeall)

Answer (score 9):

From Rspec 3 any_instance is not defined anymore.

Now use:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).and_return(1)
```

Source for this and older versions:
https://makandracards.com/makandra/2561-stub-methods-on-any-instance-of-a-class-in-rspec-1-and-rspec-2

Answer (score 0):

Updating `rspec` worked for me. You can do it using the following command:

`bundle update rspec`

Comment: My rspec was at the most recent version, in other words when I ran `sudo gem update` nothing got upgraded. What version of `rpsec` are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using `rspec 2.14.1` and it works fine. I faced the same issue as you do with `rspec 2.14.0`.

Comment: I'm using `2.14.5`, but it's interesting that it works for you at `2.14.0`

Comment: it does work at `2.14.1`, did not try higher. Have you tried to downgrade to see if that fix it?

Comment: I actually realize that my issue was not stubbing in the `before(:all)` which seems to be your issue, it was a regular stubbing issue.